# calabash-ios - symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 - linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios-simulator, calabash, calabash-ios

I am new to calabash and I am trying to use the example app available here (https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios-example) to learn calabash

I have downloaded the zipped project and followed the steps provided in the ‘Manual Setup with Xcode’ section here - https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios.

But when I attempted to build the project, it failed with the below errors.

As I was not able to resolve the errors, I deleted the -cal scheme, removed calabash framework from the framework folder in the Xcode project and used the ‘calabash-ios setup’ option. This created a new -cal scheme. But I still get the below errors when I try to build the -cal scheme. I checked the other linker flags in the build settings and it is set to the calabash framework in the project folder.

I am able to build the project without calabash scheme successfully. So this appears to be an issue with the calabash setup. Could you please let me know how do I resolve this?

```
Build target LPSimpleExample-cal
Project LPSimpleExample | Configuration Debug | Destination iPhone 6 | SKD Simulator -iOS 8.0
Ld /Users/eswar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LPSimpleExample-gwyzlvixnflcwydwrtizzsfiwete/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LPSimpleExample\ copy.app/LPSimpleExample\ copy normal i386
    cd "/Users/eswar/Workspace/calabash projects/calabash-ios-example-2"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk -L/Users/eswar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LPSimpleExample-gwyzlvixnflcwydwrtizzsfiwete/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/eswar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LPSimpleExample-gwyzlvixnflcwydwrtizzsfiwete/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/eswar/Workspace/calabash\ projects/calabash-ios-example-2 -filelist /Users/eswar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LPSimpleExample-gwyzlvixnflcwydwrtizzsfiwete/Build/Intermediates/LPSimpleExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LPSimpleExample-cal.build/Objects-normal/i386/LPSimpleExample\ copy.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -force_load /Users/eswar/Workspace/calabash\ projects/calabash-ios-example-2/calabash.framework/calabash -lstdc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -framework CFNetwork -framework MapKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework calabash -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/eswar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LPSimpleExample-gwyzlvixnflcwydwrtizzsfiwete/Build/Intermediates/LPSimpleExample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LPSimpleExample-cal.build/Objects-normal/i386/LPSimpleExample\ copy_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/eswar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LPSimpleExample-gwyzlvixnflcwydwrtizzsfiwete/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LPSimpleExample\ copy.app/LPSimpleExample\ copy

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery save:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery fetchAll:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery fetch:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_SecItemDelete", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery deleteItem:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccessible", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery save:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery query] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecAttrLabel", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery save:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecAttrService", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery query] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecAttrSynchronizable", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery query] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecAttrSynchronizableAny", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery query] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecClass", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery query] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery query] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimit", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery fetchAll:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery fetch:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimitAll", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery fetchAll:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecMatchLimitOne", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery fetch:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecReturnAttributes", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery fetchAll:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecReturnData", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery fetch:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:
      -[LPSSKeychainQuery save:] in calabash(LPSSKeychainQuery.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

A similar question has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548283/calabash-ios-link-error-ksecattrsynchronizableany-referenced-from-lpsske) and Joshua had recommended to upgrade to Xcode 5.1.1 and SDK to 7.0. But I am already using Xcode 6.01 and below are my SDK versions:

SDKs:
OS X: 10.9: (13F26)
iOS: 8.0:   (12A365)

iOS Simulator:
7.1:    (11D167)
8.0:    (12A365)

Other information:

**xcode installation location**
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

**xcode version**
Xcode 6.0.1
Build version 6A317

**calabash version**
0.11.0

**calabash.framework version**
0.11.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of missing symbols indicates that you forgot to link against Security.framework